# is $\sqrt{||T^TT||_2}$ a matrix norm of T?

Tags: matrix-norms

It's positive-valued and absolutely homogeneous, but I can't prove it satisfies the triangle inequality. I tried many "counter examples", but all of them satisify the inequality.

If we take T and K matrices, we get to this expression $\sqrt{||T^TT + K^TT + T^TK + K^TK||_2}$. And I don't know how to carry on from here

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have
$$|a+b|\le |a|+|b|,$$
then you also have
$$\sqrt{|a+b|}\le\sqrt{|a|+|b|}\le\sqrt{|a|}+\sqrt{|b|}.$$
This means that for any norm $\|\cdot\|,$ its square root is also a norm, regardless of whether you are on a matrix space etc.

**EDIT**: Actually, what I wrote above is non-sense as shown in the comments. The right way to proceed is to either know/derive the following fact:
$$\|A^TA\|_2 = \|AA^T\|_2 = \sigma(AA^T) = \sigma(A)^2=\|A\|_2^2$$
and then it's done. I am assuming you are using the usual induced $2$-norm.

Comment: The square root of a norm is in general not a norm as we have $$\sqrt{\Vert \lambda v \Vert} = \sqrt{\vert \lambda\vert} \sqrt{\Vert v\Vert}.$$

Comment: Your proof is flawed, because you do not prove $A\mapsto\|A^TA\|_2$ is a norm.

Comment: Maybe I fail to understand what is there to be proven, but from what I understand, I need to show this inequality: $\sqrt{||(K+T)^T(K+T)||_2}\leq \sqrt{||K^TK||_2} + \sqrt{||T^TT||_2}$. So how does this helps? When you open up the brackets, as seen in the OP, you get those pesky $K^TK$ and $T^TT$

Comment: @Suspicious_1 yes and you show that inequality by getting rid of that pesky square roots by following what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\|A^TA\|_2 = \|A\|_2^2$ the result follows.